# Batch script for backup hosts file

Tags: batch-file, backup

I'm writing a batch script which does the backup.

It needs to make a copy of the "hosts" file with the following condition:
"if system "hosts" file contains any uncommented entries, then copy it".

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure you have read [How di I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). With that in mind please include what you got so far.

Comment: Fine. And what is your *specific* question? Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a free coding service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commented line begin with this `"#"` string on your hosts file, so , 
you should use `Find /V "#"`  to display all lines NOT containing the specified string `"#"`

For more help about **[Find /?](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

You can do something like this :

```
@echo off
Rem Batch script to copy uncommented entries of your hosts file
set "BackupHostsFile=%userprofile%\Desktop\BackupHostsFile.txt"
If Exist "%BackupHostsFile%" Del "%BackupHostsFile%"
set "hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
Rem Find /V "#" : To display all lines NOT containing the specified string "#"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%hostspath%" ^| find /v "#"') Do (
    If Not %%a==""  echo %%a >> "%BackupHostsFile%"
)
Start "" "%BackupHostsFile%"
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this way after windows update (;-_-)